# Disable previous date and time in text-box mode "date" in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, datetime

I want to disable previous `date` and `time` in textbox (TextMode `DateTime`)

I#ve tried this in calendar control and that was successful but my requirement is to do it only in textbox.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e){
    if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now.Date){
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code which you "tried"

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik                                                                     `protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e){
        if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now.Date){
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }
  }`

Comment: @KKZone put your code in Question rather than the comment

Comment: The code you have posted is WebForms and not MVC (I have removed the tag)

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik code added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried many way to resolve this problem but finally i get this solution.

**Design**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtstartdate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code**

```
txtstartdate.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```